# SQL Error Code 1366 Incorrect integer value at row 88163

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to do the following query

```
INSERT INTO 'table_1'(column_1)  
    SELECT DISTINCT 'column 2'  
    FROM other_schema.table2;
```

Both of those columns have their fields set to INT(255), and yet I get the following error:

"Error Code: 1366. Incorrect integer value: 'column2' for column 'column2' at row 88163"

I even went and checked the individual row, but the field is a number(5800 to be precise).

I did some tinkering, and it seems that if I try to limit the select, it always accuses the row immediately after the upper limit of being of an incorrect value.

Comment: `int(255)` really doesn't make sense for an integer in MySQL.  What are you trying to store there?

Comment: If you have single quotes as in your code now, then the code will fail to compile and not run.  You should remove them, as I did in my original edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you've written your query currently is that you're trying to `INSERT` a string into your integer column. When you do

`SELECT DISTINCT 'column2'`

you are selecting the literal string `'column2'` and not the values from that column. I would unquote the references to your table and column:

`INSERT INTO table
SELECT DISTINCT column2 FROM ...`

Comment: The issue is that the name of the column has spaces, making it give error 1064 if I try to run it as you said.

Comment: There's another answer to this question that has the solution for this: escaping your column / table names with backticks `.

Answer (score 1):

If you use single quotes around 'column 2' sql will interpret that as a string, you need to remove the quote, or add backticks ` if the table name has spaces

```
SELECT DISTINCT `column 2`
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems pretty clear to me that `table2(column2)` is not a number.  You may think it is for some reason, but it is not.

However, `table1(column1)` *is* a number.  So, one method to solve this is to use silent conversion.  That is, convert the value to a number but in such a way that no error occurs.  MySQL does this with `+ 0`:

```
INSERT INTO table1(column1)  
    SELECT DISTINCT (column2 + 0) 
    FROM other_schema.table2;
```

I would suggest adding `where (column2 + 0) <> 0`, assuming that you never expect 0 for this column.

I should also note that you have no idea what row is 88,163 for the `insert`.  This takes place after the `distinct`, so it is very unlikely that it is the row identified as 88,168th in the table.